# Prove $||x+y||=||x||+||y||$ in a Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

> Consider an infinite dimensional Hilbert Space. Prove $$||x+y||=||x||+||y||$$.

I immediately thought of two identities:

Parallelogram equality: $||x+y||^2+||x-y||^2=2(||x||^2+||y||^2)$

Cauchy-Schwarz equality: $\langle x,y \rangle\leqslant ||x||||y||$

I realized that if $x=\lambda y=\frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\langle y,y\rangle}y$, then  $\langle x,y \rangle = ||x||||y||$

Now attempt derivation:

$||x+y||^2=\langle x+y,x+y\rangle=||x||^2+||y||^2+2\langle x,y\rangle$

Now assuming that $x=\lambda y$

$||x+y||^2=\langle x+y,x+y\rangle=||x||^2+||y||^2+ 2||x|||y||$

Now I do not know how to proceed.

**Question**:

Am I on the right track? If so, then how should I proceed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are $x$ and $y$?  If $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary elements of your Hilbert space, then this is not true.

Comment: I don't think the question is correct - take 2-dimensional Euclidean space with the natural dot product, then this fails on the basis vectors.

Comment: @Aweygan This is the exercise I was given. Perhaps it is intended to find the conditions that allow the equality to be true.

Comment: Maybe you are supposed to show the triangle *in*equality $\|x+y\| \le \|x\|+\|y\|$.

Comment: @gerw No I am not.

Comment: Yes, I'd suggest that you find the conditions under which that equality holds.

Comment: The infinite-dimensionally is not going to be important the way the problem is posed. When $x$ and $y$ are given, anything can be seen in the space spanned by $x$ and $y$; that space has dimension at most $2$. So you might as well consider a 2-dimensional Hilbert space. But then you might as well consider the usual $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then the length of the sum can be this big only if $x$ and $y$ are in the same direction.

Comment: @TedShifrin That is what I am trying to find as I go along with derivation.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I guess that I have already assumed that by stating that $x=\lambda y$. Right?

Comment: @PedroGomes if $x=\lambda y$ you can calculate $$||x+y||$$  and $||x||+||y||$ directly

Comment: @clark Please tell me how.

Comment: $||x+y|| = ||  (1+\lambda)y ||=(1+\lambda)||y||$

Comment: @clark Do you  think this the most universal assumption that assure the equality holds?

Comment: yes this holds if and only if $x=\lambda y$

Comment: @TedShifrin Please check the update!

Comment: If you can assume $x=\lambda y$ and also $\lambda\ge 0$, then clearly $$\| x+y \| = \| \lambda y + y\| = \| (\lambda + 1)y\| = (\lambda+1) \| y \| = \lambda \| y \| + \| y \| = \|\lambda y\| + \| y \| = \| x \| + \| y \|$$ That only works because both $\lambda+1$ and $\lambda$ are non-negative.

Comment: If the typographical difference between $\|x\|$ and $||x||$ is not conspicuous to you, look at the difference between $\|x\|\|y\|$ and $||x|| ||y||.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide by $||x||+||y||$ and we want to have 
$$||z+w||=1$$
Where $||z|| + || w||=1$.

So, using your derivation

\begin{align*}
||z+w||^2&=||z||^2+||w||^2 +2<z,w>\\
&\leq ||z||^2+||w||^2 +2||z||||w||\\
&=(||z||+||w||)^2 =1
\end{align*}
Therefore, $<z,w>=||z|| ||w||$.

Since the Cauchy-Schwartz equality holds if and only $z,w$ are linearly dependent, we get that 
$x=\lambda  y$.

So,  $$||x+y|| =|(1+\lambda)||x||,\quad ||x||+||y||=(1+|\lambda|)||x||$$
If $||x||\neq 0$,
we obtain $\lambda = |\lambda |$, hence $\lambda >0$.

To sum up, the inequality holds if and only if $x=\lambda y$ where $\lambda \geq 0$.